# How to keep the document-tabs sorted by their last usage in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

What is the registry change to tell Visual Studio to always position the current document in the window to the left.

The default implementation is such that if you have 10 documents open and you are editing the 5th one it's tab will be the 5th tab in the group. With the registry change when you click on the tab for the 5th document it becomes the 1st tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(From [Sara Ford's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/10/09/did-you-know-you-can-keep-recently-used-files-from-falling-off-the-file-tab-channel-331.aspx)):

Under the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0** key create a **DWORD UseMRUDocOrdering = 1**.

BTW: the above is for Visual Studio 2008. For Visual Studio 2005, replace **9.0** in the registry key name with **8.0**.

Comment: +1, Neat. I almost responded with "that's not possible" but I feared a registry hack was hiding somewhere.