# Is there an MRU Document order feature in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2005/2008 you could have your documents automatically arrange by the most recently used. The [registry setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619500/how-to-keep-the-document-tabs-sorted-by-their-last-usage-in-visual-studio) doesn't work for Visual Studio 2010. Does anybody know how to enable this feature for 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an undocumented feature in VS 2005/2008. I was a big fan of it as well, and was wondering what happened to it. It appears that they've axed the feature from VS 2010.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526072/enable-mru-doc-ordering-in-visual-studio-2010